# Extending AutoQueryServiceBase

Tags: c#, servicestack

I'm trying to extend the ServiceStack AutoQuery service base as documented here:
https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms#intercept-and-introspect-every-query

I haven't added any of my own code, I've just started by using the code exactly as they are in the documentation. However after registering this custom AutoQuery service base in the plugin registration, I'm getting a 404 (handler for Request not found) when running my queries.

Am I missing anything?

The request DTO is just a very basic one:

```
[Route("/query/persons")]
public class QueryPersons : QueryBase<Person>
{
}
```

Registration code in AppHost.cs:

```
Plugins.Add(new AutoQueryFeature { 
    AutoQueryServiceBaseType = typeof(MyAutoQueryServiceBase),
    MaxLimit = 20000
});
```

MyAutoQueryServiceBase.cs:

```
public abstract class MyAutoQueryServiceBase : AutoQueryServiceBase
{
    public override object Exec<From>(ServiceStack.IQuery<From> dto)
    {
        var q = AutoQuery.CreateQuery(dto, Request.GetRequestParams());
        return AutoQuery.Execute(dto, q);
    }

    public override object Exec<From, Into>(IQuery<From, Into> dto)
    {
        var q = AutoQuery.CreateQuery(dto, Request.GetRequestParams());
        return AutoQuery.Execute(dto, q);
    }
}
```

Request headers:

> GET /api/query/persons HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
> Connection: keep-alive
> Pragma: no-cache
> Cache-Control: no-cache
> Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
> Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
> Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
> Cookie: ; __ngDebug=false; ASP.NET_SessionId=0129B010A336F8DB0BD63E01; _okdetect=%7B%22token%22%3A%2214490327946950%22%2C%22proto%22%3A%22http%3A%22%2C%22host%22%3A%22127.0.0.1%3A4040%22%7D; _okbk=cd4%3Dtrue%2Cvi5%3D0%2Cvi4%3D1449032795003%2Cvi3%3Dactive%2Cvi2%3Dfalse%2Cvi1%3Dfalse%2Ccd8%3Dchat%2Ccd6%3D0%2Ccd5%3Daway%2Ccd3%3Dfalse%2Ccd2%3D0%2Ccd1%3D0%2C; _ok=1700-237-10-3483; olfsk=olfsk9099740379024297; hblid=BpXKVv7dAWFMaUMm3m39N5BKJEQ0JEOa; wcsid=k1bOWEeYTubNhz8m3m39N5BKJEQEJ0OB; _oklv=1449040260289%2Ck1bOWEeYTubNhz8m3m39N5BKJEQEJ0OB; _gat=1; _ga=GA1.1.449006996.1430457179; ss-id=xyUzzneZ3O2uAeZjLgJX; ss-pid=6ZEnqD2sG9T8SOwx2JmE; X-UAId=1333

Response headers:

> HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found
> Date: Sun, 10 Jan 2016 23:36:03 GMT
> Server: Mono.WebServer.XSP/3.0.0.0 MacOSX
> Vary: Accept
> X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/4.050 Unix/Mono
> X-MiniProfiler-Ids: ["48eeb6c2-d09b-47c0-a598-da0219242294","2613208e-42cb-4b4c-ab9c-7664a92acb3e","e2f1c5ad-f190-4314-bed9-9ee2eb4890d9"]
> X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
> Content-Length: 154
> Cache-Control: private
> Content-Type: text/plain
> Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=81
> Connection: Keep-Alive

StartUpErrors from ?debug=requestinfo:

```
"StartUpErrors": [
{
  "ErrorCode": "NullReferenceException",
  "Message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object",
  "StackTrace": "[Object: 12/01/2016 11:47:15 PM]:\n[REQUEST: ]\nSystem.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object\n  at ServiceStack.HostConfig.<get_RazorNamespaces>b__b (System.Xml.Linq.XElement x) [0x00011] in <filename unknown>:0 \n  at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T].ForEach (System.Action`1 action) [0x00035] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.2.0-branch/bockbuild-mono-4.2.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.2.1/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs:593 \n  at ServiceStack.HostConfig.get_RazorNamespaces () [0x00064] in <filename unknown>:0 \n  at ServiceStack.Formats.MarkdownFormat.Register (IAppHost appHost) [0x0004c] in <filename unknown>:0 \n  at ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost.LoadPluginsInternal (ServiceStack.IPlugin[] plugins) [0x0000a] in <filename unknown>:0 ",
  "Errors": [],
  "Meta": null
},
{
  "ErrorCode": "ArgumentNullException",
  "Message": "Value cannot be null.\nParameter name: obj",
  "StackTrace": "[Object: 12/01/2016 11:47:15 PM]:\n[REQUEST: ]\nSystem.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.\nParameter name: obj\n  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.Emit.ModuleBuilder:getToken (System.Reflection.Emit.ModuleBuilder,object,bool)\n  at System.Reflection.Emit.ModuleBuilder.GetToken (System.Reflection.MemberInfo member, Boolean create_open_instance) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.2.0-branch/bockbuild-mono-4.2.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.2.1/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection.Emit/ModuleBuilder.cs:676 \n  at System.Reflection.Emit.ModuleBuilderTokenGenerator.GetToken (System.Reflection.MemberInfo member, Boolean create_open_instance) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.2.0-branch/bockbuild-mono-4.2.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.2.1/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection.Emit/ModuleBuilder.cs:977 \n  at System.Reflection.Emit.ILGenerator.Emit (OpCode opcode, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo con) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.2.0-branch/bockbuild-mono-4.2.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.2.1/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection.Emit/ILGenerator.cs:520 \n  at ServiceStack.AutoQueryFeature.GenerateMissingServices (IEnumerable`1 misingRequestTypes) [0x00082] in <filename unknown>:0 \n  at ServiceStack.AutoQueryFeature.AfterPluginsLoaded (IAppHost appHost) [0x00079] in <filename unknown>:0 \n  at ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost.AfterPluginsLoaded (System.String specifiedContentType) [0x000ab] in <filename unknown>:0 ",
  "Errors": [
    {
      "ErrorCode": "ArgumentNullException",
      "FieldName": "obj",
      "Message": "Value cannot be null.\n"
    }
  ],
  "Meta": null
}
```

]

Comment: The HTTP 404 Not Found Error means that the webpage you were trying to reach could not be found on the server. It is a Client-side Error which means that either the page has been removed or moved and the URL was not changed accordingly, or that you typed in the URL incorrectly.

Comment: that means your hitting wrong endpoint.debug your method and post a exact errors.

Comment: The URL exists and works fine if I remove the custom code from the documentation. It only stops working when I add that custom code, which to me should not be doing anything since the logic is not changed.

Comment: @vonec please post the code you used to register the AutoQuery plugin as well as the raw HTTP Request and Response HTTP Headers (you can get using Chrome Web Inspector or Fiddler).

Comment: @mythz I've updated the OP to include the registration code and request/response headers and the MyAutoQueryServiceBase class is exactly the same as the one in the documentation.

Comment: @vonec can you confirm that it's the base class causing the issue? e.g. do you still get a 404 if `AutoQueryServiceBaseType` was commented out? If so can you also include the source code of `MyAutoQueryServiceBase`. Also are you trying to run this on OSX/Mono?

Comment: @mythz I don't get a 404 if I comment out AutoQueryServiceBaseType, I've updated the OP with the code for MyAutoQueryServiceBase and yes I am running on OSX/Mono (Xamarin Studio).

Comment: @vonec can you try with the latest v4.0.51 that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet)

Comment: @mythz tried 4.0.51 and getting the same issue. Not sure if this helps, but it looks like it's having trouble getting registered because I don't see it in autoquery/metadata. However if I don't use MyAutoQueryServiceBase, I can see the metadata fine.

Comment: @vonec Can you update your question to include any StartUpErrors listed in [?debug=requestinfo](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Debugging#request-info)

Comment: @mythz done, looks like some ArgumentNullException

Comment: @vonec ok but I thought I fixed this in the latest v4.0.51 MyGet package. Are you sure you're not using stale/cached v4.0.51 packages? I've added a [AutoQueryTest project](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Test/blob/master/src/AutoQueryTest/AutoQueryTest/Global.asax.cs) which now works on Mono/OSX. Can you send me a link to a project (e.g. on GitHub) that repro's the issue?

Comment: @mythz I just tried that test project and it works even on 4.0.50, need more time to dig into it, I don't have a project I can share right now.

Comment: @mythz I was able to reproduce the issue with the AutoQueryTest project. The 404 issue happens when the SS packages are referenced from a package. To repro, remove the references to the SS packages and add them via nuget. By doing this you should see a bunch of references in the csproj file which looks like ```<HintPath>..\..\packages\ServiceStack.4.0.50\lib\net40\ServiceStack.dll</HintPath>```
For some reason when the DLLs are referenced this way the routing fails to resolve. Can you please comment? Is this not the normal practice?

Comment: @vonec I doubt it has anything to do with how the dlls are referenced, it's likely the version of dlls you're using, try upgrading to the latest version.

Comment: @mythz I guess it was the ArgumentNullException issue, because the version I tried was 4.0.50 and upgrading to 4.0.54 works now. Thanks!